# How to select data of a column one by one from database and display it to label

Tags: c#, database, windows, forms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to programming, I have a database with one column called task and one column date, I need to select the tasks for today's date one by one from database and display it to a label. I tried but could only get only display first task to label.

```
cmd.commandText = "select task from table2 where date  ='"+DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")+"'";
Var n = cmd.ExecuteReader();
n.Read();
label5.Text = n.GetString(0);
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `using` on disposable objects.
Use a datareader, and read each row. For each row, add the taskname to your label.

```
        string cnstring = "<your connection string>";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(cnstring))
        {
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select task from table2 where date  ='" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "'";
                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    while (dr.Read())
                        label5.Text += dr.GetString(0) + " ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: When i replace as,  label5.Text =. dr.GetString(0), why cant i get the strings one by one

Comment: you would just set the label over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Just use the select query with where clause `select 'task from table name where date = 'your date;' and fetch result one by one using row fetch and display wherever you want

Comment: What is row fetch

Comment: what language are you using and what code you have tried please explain?